# Django Default main page functionality

Tags: django

i have installed DJANGO 1.5, once entered 127.0.01:8000 the beautiful HTLM page appears.

```
"it worked"
```

now whatever i enter in the Browser URL, it always goto default welcome page.

once i start playing with url.py this functionality get vanished. and i start getting 404 page.

is there any way to keep this functionality on i.e what ever is typed in the browser url it goes to main page exception for  the defined url in url.py

please help

url.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from article.views import HelloTemplate

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^hello_template/$', 'article.views.hello_template'),
    url(r'^hello_template_simple/$', 'article.views.hello_template_simple'),
```

other code snippet for "myproject/urls.py"

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^myapp/', include('myproject.myapp.urls')),
    (r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/myapp/list/')), 
    (r'', 'myproject.myapp.views'),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: maybe you should post your midified `url.py` to get help with finding out what went wrong

Comment: Have you removed the route for '^$'?

Comment: @bpgergo: i have added url.py in the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a your default page as a catch-all URL *at the end* of the other URLs:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello_template_simple/$', 'article.views.hello_template_simple'),
    url(r'', 'article.views.hello_template'),
```

Now any URL which isn't matched by hello_template_simple will be caught by hello_template.

Comment: it works but if i try to put same concept in this code, it does not. please guide what is wrong with it "urlpatterns = patterns('',

 (r'^myapp/', include('myproject.myapp.urls')),
 (r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/myapp/list/')), 
 (r'', 'myproject.myapp.views'),"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying doesn't work, here. What happens?

Comment: my mistake, its working now, as i was trying to hardcode the view instated of url in this case. thanks a lot